# How do character upgrades interact with Dispatcher's special ability?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

(This should be spoiler free, all of this info is available at the start of the season.)

In our game we upgraded the dispatcher with the Pilot upgrade to Direct Flight without discarding the card. Pilot seems especially powerful since the dispatcher can then move anyone to himself and then trade them that cities card.

Last night the question arose about could he Direct Flight another player's pawn without discarding the city card and without moving himself to that city, for example, moving the medic to a city with a cured disease to instantly treat it?

My instinct says that this is a legal use, as the Dispatcher ability says "Move another player's pawn as if it is your own" and his pawn has the ability to Direct Flight without discarding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are legal ways to use the Dispatcher's special ability in Pandemic?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/what-are-legal-ways-to-use-the-dispatchers-special-ability-in-pandemic)

Comment: @JoeW This is not a duplicate as that question is about pandemic and not Pandemic legacy. This is specifically about the mechanics introduced in legacy

Comment: The rules apply the same way to both game so the answer is the same to both.

Comment: @JoeW The pilot upgrade literally does not exist in Pandemic so it is impossible for the answer to be the same.

Comment: @JoeW Not a dupe, as character upgrades are not a part of vanilla Pandemic. The essence of this question is about the upgrade that the Dispatcher has, and whether it can be used in conjunction with the regular Dispatcher ability

Comment: I don't see this as an issue of the upgrades existing or not but how it interacts with the rules, In this case it just modifies the rules to prevent discarding the card in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a legal move, and it is clarified in the [rules](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/26/94/2694b3fb-c718-4f87-9bdd-bbea0fdadcbe/zm7172_pandemic_legacys1_red_rules.pdf) (page 5) (emphasis mine):

> When the Dispatcher moves a player’s pawn as if it were his own:
>
> • **use the Dispatcher’s scars and upgrades**, not those belonging to the
>   character he is moving,
>
> • **cards that need to be played or discarded** (for Direct and Charter Flights
>   or to enter a collapsing or fallen city) **come from the Dispatcher’s hand**.
>   A card discarded for a Charter Flight must match the city the pawn is
>   moving from.

The *Pilot* upgrade allows your character to take a Direct Flight without discarding the card. I don't see an upgrade that allows you to take a Charter Flight without discarding, however, so be sure you're using the correct action. Looking around on google, a *Pilot* Dispatcher is a very common combination, as it is very efficient to move players around that way.

Comment: I was confusing Charter Flight and Direct Flight, you are correct I was referring to the pilot upgrade. I will edit to fix that.

I didn't want to google too heavily for fear of spoilers, so thank you for doing that.